# router command to change bandwidth limit for a MAC address

Tags: openwrt, router, tc, dd-wrt, qos

I use DD-WRT to limit WAN bandwidth to one MAC address using DD-WRT's web interface.
The key entry in the web interface (in "NAT/QoS" tab's "QOS" tab) is "MAC priority",
which I normally set to 10000 "WAN Max Down kBits".

I temporarily sometimes increase this value to 60000, but this is never needed
permanently, so it seems wasteful to set this in the web interface (since it overwrites
the NVRAM flash memory which has limited write cycles before wear-out).

So, is there a way to temporarily increase this value with some command I could issue
during a telnet session (and does not overwrite the NVRAM)?  I have tried some
wild guesses with the tc command, but been unsuccessful.

Comment: Don't worry about the limited write cycles. Yes, everything wears out eventually but such chips last a LOT longer than the router itself.

Comment: @ChanganAuto What if I do this change back and forth once per minute?  At some point, I need to worry.

Comment: You can do that for years in a row and the chip will still outlive the other components, namely capacitors. And even if nothing else fails you'll still be far from half of its expected lifetime when the router becomes hopelessly obsolete.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I guess there is no one-line solution here...  Could a moderator migrate this question to the serverfault site? or should I just repost there? or should I just give up?

Comment: If such migration ever happened it would be rejected. Your question is fine here. Disagreeing with the premise and alerting for the unfounded assumptions doesn't mean it isn't on-topic. Whether it deserves an actual answer is debatable though because in providing one it would sort of validate it. IMO, it shouldn't be validated at all.